# Elastic beanstalk - create environment using existing security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to create environment in elasticbean stalk using existing security groups, in such a way that new security groups are not created?

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in the configuration file for your environment like this:

```
 option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    SecurityGroups: 'my-securitygroup'
```

You can manage config files with `eb config`.